# how to use Yiic message command with CDbMessageSource

Tags: yii

i used to use CPhpMessageSource but i want to try CDbMessageSource i though i just have to change this...

```
'components' => array(
        'message' => array(
//            'class' => 'CPhpMessageSource',
            'class' => 'CDbMessageSource',
        ),
```

But when i exectute Yiic message to insert translation data in the database it still generate files in protected/messages/"files".php
...

i must have miss one point...

i follow this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMessageSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Yii has a "reader" for database translations, it doesn't have a "writer". What I usually end up doing is writing some code that can populate the tables using the generated translation files.

You can also write a derivated "message" command for Yii and use that to insert in the database directly, it's not that much work:

```
<?php

Yii::import('system.cli.commands.MessageCommand', TRUE);

class DbMessageCommand extends MessageCommand
{
   protected function generateMessageFile($messages,$fileName,$overwrite,$removeOld,$sort)
   {
      if (preg_match('@/(..)/([^\\/:"*?<>|]+?)\.php$@i', $fileName, $matches))
      {
         $language = $matches[1];
         $category = $matches[2];

         foreach ($messages as $message)
         {
            // $message contains the string, $category has the category and $language is the current language
            // Add to your DB here
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Just create a `DbMessageCommand.php` file in your commands subdirectory and finish the code and you should be in business.

In short, what this does is use the regular message command to parse the files, but when the `generateMessageFile`-function is called to write to the php file, it uses a regexp to determine what would be written (it's called per language/category) and adds it in the database.

I haven't included that code, because I don't use the models as they are included in Yii. I have my own `CDbMessageSource`-variant and my own string tables.